# ¿Cómo puedo optimizar la insercion a una base de datos phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

He estado trabajando en un proyecto de la universidad, el programa tiene que leer lineas de un archivo de texto con el siguiente formato: NRC,ST,DEPARTAMENTO,AREA,CLAVE,MATERIA,HRS_TEORIA,HRS_LAB,SECC,CRED,
CUPO,OCUP,DISP,INI,FIN,L,M,I,J,V,S,EDIF,AULA,PROFESOR,FECHA INICIO,FECHA FIN,NIVEL
Para posteriormente insertarse en una base de datos, lo que yo hago es leer línea por línea e insertar, funciona, pero el problema es que toma casi 5 minutos y se me pide que no pase de 30 segundos.
Este es mi bucle:

```
while(!feof($myfile)) 
{
    $linea = fgets($myfile);
    $campos = explode(",", $linea);
    $nrc = $campos[0];
    $estatus = $campos[1];
    $departamento = $campos[2];
    $area = $campos[3];
    $clave = $campos[4];
    $materia = $campos[5];
    $hrs_teoria = $campos[6];
    $hrs_lab = $campos[7];
    $seccion = $campos[8];
    $creditos = $campos[9];
    $cupos_totales = $campos[10];
    $cupos_ocupados = $campos[11];
    $cupos_disponibles = $campos[12];
    $inicio = $campos[13];
    $fin = $campos[14];
    $lunes = $campos[15];
    $martes = $campos[16];
    $miercoles = $campos[17];
    $jueves = $campos[18];
    $viernes = $campos[19];
    $sabado = $campos[20];
    $edificio = $campos[21];
    $aula = $campos[22];
    $apellido_profesor  = $campos[23];
    $nombre_profesor = $campos[24];
    $nombre_profesor = preg_replace("/\((.*?)\)/i", "", $nombre_profesor);
    $codigo_profesor = filter_var($campos[24], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $fecha_inicio = $campos[25];
    $fecha_fin = $campos[26];
    $nivel = $campos[27];
    // Asignar información leída a las variables para una lectura más clara

    $sql = "INSERT INTO curso (materia, departamento, area, clave, creditos, cupos_totales, horas_laboratorio, 
    horas_teoria, nivel, fecha_inicio, fecha_fin)
    VALUES ($materia, $departamento, $area, $clave, $creditos, $cupos_totales, $hrs_lab, $hrs_teoria, $nivel, $fecha_inicio, $fecha_fin)";
    $conn->query($sql);
    //Insertar a curso

    $sql = "INSERT INTO profesor (codigo, nombre, apellido)
    VALUES ($codigo_profesor, '$nombre_profesor', '$apellido_profesor')";
    $conn->query($sql);
    //insertar a profesor

    $sql = "INSERT INTO clase (estatus, nrc, seccion, cupos_ocupados, cupos_disponibles, edificio, aula, inicio, fin, 
    lunes, martes, miercoles, jueves, viernes, sabado, codigo_profesor, clave)
    VALUES ($estatus, $nrc, $seccion, $cupos_ocupados, $cupos_disponibles, $edificio, $aula, $inicio, $fin, 
    '$lunes', '$martes', '$miercoles', '$jueves', '$viernes', '$sabado', $codigo_profesor, $clave)";
    $conn->query($sql);
    //insertar a materia
}*/
$conn->close();
fclose($myfile);
```

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Has probado con un procedimiento almacenado?

Comment: Puedes usar insert con varios values. INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9); Según en la documentación de MySQL dice lo siguiente: "INSERT statements that use VALUES syntax can insert multiple rows". Acá el enlace: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html

Comment: Este problema lo he experimentado con otros lenguajes y otras bases de datos, el problema en si no es por hacer varias instrucciones, es por que cada instrucción necesita realizar el commit de la información, lo primero que haría es enviar esas instrucciones en batch con **$conn->multi_query($sql)**, esto implica que concatenes las instrucciones insert y las separes con punto y coma (;), lo otro es hacer el manejo manual del commit, y solo llamar el commit por ahi cada 1000 registros, pero es algo que debes cuadrar manualmente a prueba y error a ver si con 1000 esta o ok o con menos o mas....

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos, me sirvieron bastante sus comentarios, investigué sobre como insertar múltiples filas y ahora inserta todo en 4 segundos.